# BufferedReader will not read final line of input

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm having this problem right now solving a problem (practice for java). The problem wants to make sure the brackets of the input provided are in correct order (more info in this link: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/matching-brackets). The issue I'm faced with is that my bufferedReader will not read my final line of input. It makes it into the final loop, but seems to "pause" before reading it. The only way I can get it to work is if I press enter, then the program continues past the input.readLine() for the final time and prints out my string. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("input data:");
    //First line is read to take in the number of lines for input will follow
    int data = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    int i = 0;

    while(i < data)
    {
    //temp string builder to hold the wanted characters
    StringBuilder stringy = new StringBuilder();
    String line = input.readLine();
    //temp string builder holding the entire line
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
        for(int j = 0; j < sb.length(); j++)
        {
            //loops through string builder & adds the wanted characters to stringy
            switch(sb.charAt(j)){
            case '(' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;

            case ')' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;

            case ']' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;

            case '[' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;

            case '{' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;

            case '}' : stringy.append(sb.charAt(j));
            break;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(stringy);

        i++;
    }
    }catch(IOException x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Sorry if I'm not clear enough. I've tried to read up on this online but people don't seem to have this specific problem. I'm not sure how, but it seems that an extra line or something was added before my last line of input. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

edit:
sorry, I realize I did not provide any input data for the program. Here it is:

```
4
(a+[b*c]-{d/3}) 
(a + [b * c) - 17]
((a * x) + [b] * y) + c
auf(zlo)men [gy<psy>] four{s}
```

Just copy and paste the above in your program and you'll see the issue

Comment: The program seems to work correctly. For example, if you enter `5` in the first `readLine()` (data), then it will ask you 5 new values for matching brackets. Each time, you will have to press "enter" once to provide those 5 inputs. So, what's the issue?

Comment: its working fine check this http://ideone.com/uo8gN3

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide the input information I've been using. I figured it might have something to do with copying and pasting input into the server area.

Comment: I realize that you end up getting all of the input, I guess I just don't understand why I need to press enter for the final line of input even though it shows me what I want for the first three lines. The while loop seems to pause right before or on the line where the bufferedReader reads the final line of input. Kind of a different question, but it is just really bugging me.

Comment: You mean you have to press enter an extra time? On mine you just press it once for the last input. Are you running in your IDE, or command line?

Comment: I'm running it in my IDE. I copy and paste the input into the IDE and it instantly displays the results up to the last answer. To get the final answer, I need to press enter. The final answer has a space in between it and the rest of the results. I press enter once too, I'm just not sure why I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

The [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method blocks on I/O reading the input until it finds a line terminator character in the input.  The final line of your input is different from all other lines in that it does not have a line terminator character at the end.  Pressing enter in the terminal adds the required line terminator character, but as a side effect it also causes the terminal to advance its cursor down a line, causing the "space in between" lines that you noticed.  This isn't really unexpected behavior, and it's not a bug in your code, but you can "fix" it by making sure you have a line terminator character at the end of the last line of your input.

## The Details

I can reproduce the behavior you described.  I compile the code, run it, and then paste in the sample input.  Just like you said, it hangs on the last line.  I then press enter, which causes it to proceed, but why was that necessary?  There is also an unexpected gap before the last result.

```
> java Test
input data:
4
(a+[b*c]-{d/3}) 
(a + [b * c) - 17]
((a * x) + [b] * y) + c
auf(zlo)men [gy<psy>] four{s}([]{})
([)]
(()[])

()[]{}
```

I also noticed another problem that you hadn't mentioned.  In the seventh line in the sample above (the line starting with "auf"), the result was printed right afterwards without moving to a new line.

Hey, what's going on here?  Well, let's try to apply some debugging techniques.  [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) is a tool that ships with the JDK that lets you attach to a running JVM and dump the state of its threads of execution.  It's a great way to get a glimpse at what your code is really doing when it runs.  Let's try running jstack right when the process appears to hang.  First though, I need to identify the process ID of the JVM.  Let's use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) to do that.

```
> jps
83518 Test

> jstack 83518
2015-12-24 21:25:17
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode):

...

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbba2001000 nid=0x1903 runnable [0x000000010a560000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000007aaa9a5f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    - locked <0x00000007aab2ad88> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    - locked <0x00000007aab2ad88> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)

...
```

I've trimmed the output of jstack to show just the relevant main thread.  That's interesting.  I can see the main entry point: `Test.main`.  I can see the call to `BufferedReader#readLine`.  After a series of other method calls, it lands in `FileInputStream#read`.  If I run jstack multiple times, I keep seeing the same thing.  That means execution is stuck in that method trying to read bytes from the input.  That's odd.  What would explain that?  Maybe the JavaDocs for [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) contain some explanation of the behavior.

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

At this point, let's try to form a hypothesis.  What could potentially cause the process to get stuck trying to read data?  The JavaDocs say a line is considered terminated by a particular character.  Perhaps our final line of input doesn't contain a line terminating character.

To confirm that theory, let's try looking at a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) dump of our input.  I usually use the [xxd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) command line tool to do this.  Here are the results.

```
0000000: 340a 2861 2b5b 622a 635d 2d7b 642f 337d  4.(a+[b*c]-{d/3}
0000010: 2920 0a28 6120 2b20 5b62 202a 2063 2920  ) .(a + [b * c) 
0000020: 2d20 3137 5d0a 2828 6120 2a20 7829 202b  - 17].((a * x) +
0000030: 205b 625d 202a 2079 2920 2b20 630a 6175   [b] * y) + c.au
0000040: 6628 7a6c 6f29 6d65 6e20 5b67 793c 7073  f(zlo)men [gy<ps
0000050: 793e 5d20 666f 7572 7b73 7d              y>] four{s}
```

I'm testing on a Mac which uses a single control character, LF (line feed), to indicate a new line.  This may be different on other platforms.  Most notably, Windows uses a sequence of 2 control characters: CR/LF (carriage return/line feed).  According to the [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) standard, the ASCII code for LF is 0a in hex representation.  This is shown in the [Basic Latin(ASCII)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) code chart.  Going back to our hex dump, we can see 4 occurrences of the 0a character, and note that there is no 0a character at the end of the final line.

This is starting to look like a promising theory.  What else can we do to verify it?  Thanks to [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/), we can view the source code implementation of many of the common JDK classes, including `BufferedReader`.  Let's try looking at the implementation of [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/ab44843d5891/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#l305).  This is a pretty tricky loop, but the bottom line is that it tracks "end of line" in a variable named `eol`, and that's the condition that causes it to quit filling its internal buffer in the `fill` method and instead return a string to the caller.

```
charLoop:
    for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
        c = cb[i];
        if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
            eol = true;
            break charLoop;
        }
    }

    startChar = nextChar;
    nextChar = i;

    if (eol) {
        String str;
        if (s == null) {
            str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
        } else {
            s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
            str = s.toString();
        }
        nextChar++;
        if (c == '\r') {
            skipLF = true;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

OK, now I'm convinced!  Let's test the hypothesis by repeating our original test, but this time let's make sure we have a line terminator at the end of our final line.  Copy-pasting that version of the input in, I now see these results.

```
> java Test
input data:
4
(a+[b*c]-{d/3}) 
(a + [b * c) - 17]
((a * x) + [b] * y) + c
auf(zlo)men [gy<psy>] four{s}
([]{})
([)]
(()[])
()[]{}
```

That's more like it!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this answer. This explanation was just what I needed. I definitely plan on using these tools in the future to look for problems in my code, I seriously had no clue they existed! It was probably pretty easy to tell from this I'm a novice programmer,  but I'll be using these tools in the future to tune in my skills. Once again, thank you for this answer, you really cleared up a lot of stuff for me.

Comment: @DaveCooney, I'm glad to hear it helped!  No worries.  We were all novices once.  :-)  If this was helpful, then please consider accepting the answer and/or upvoting.