# What is causing missing characters and incorrect starting location when creating a maze from a text file?

Tags: java, maze

I'm converting a text file into a two dimensional char array and getting indexes of specific chars.

I have this task where I need to read the map which is text file, and find the shortest route out. So far I converted the text file into a char array, but if I'm printing out the map on console, some of the chars are missing. For some reason I don't understand, I'm not getting correct location for the starting point.

My idea to use same logic I found about binary maze. If you read this and think I'm doing something completely stupid, then please let me know.

First, I created two methods to get how many rows and columns there are in the map:

```
private static int getRowsOfTheMap() throws IOException {
    int rows = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = getReader(filePath);
    while (reader.readLine() != null) rows++;
    reader.close();
    return rows;
}

private static int getColumnsOfTheMap() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = getReader(filePath);
    String firstRow = reader.readLine();

    return firstRow.length();
}
```

Then, I created a method to get the map as 2D char array:

```
private static char[][] getMapFromFile() throws IOException {

    char[][] map = new char[getRowsOfTheMap()][getColumnsOfTheMap()];

    BufferedReader reader = getReader(filePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = (char) reader.read();
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

And method for getting starting point:

```
private static int[] getStartingPoint(char[][] map) {
    int[] startingPoint = {
        -1,
        -1
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == 'X') {
                startingPoint[0] = i;
                startingPoint[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return startingPoint;
}
```

Map from the text file and map output.

[image: The map from the text file:] [image: Map after I converted it into char array]

And with location expected is [1,2] actual is [1,3]

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Look out for line separators

Comment: How is [1, 2] the correct output for the given input? Can you please provide the problem link?

Comment: Don't use a BufferedReader; use a Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce the correct map, and `[1, 2]` as a starting-point with the following code; adapted from yours.

I created a `Maze` class, with a `map` method to populate the `map`, `rows`, and `columns` fields.
Additionally, I created a `startingPoint` method to return an `int[]` of the starting point row and column indices.
Finally, I created an overridden `toString` method for printing the maze.

You can utilize `Arrays.binarySearch` to find `X`.

```java
class Maze {
    File file;
    char[][] map;
    int rows, columns;

    Maze(String path) throws IOException {
        file = new File(path);
        map();
    }

    void map() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String newline = System.lineSeparator();
            rows = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (rows++ != 0) string.append(newline);
                string.append(line);
                columns = line.length();
            }
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string.toString()));
        map = new char[rows][columns];
        int index = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            map[index++] = line.toCharArray();
    }

    int[] startPoint() {
        int index = 0;
        int column;
        for (char[] row : map) {
            if ((column = Arrays.binarySearch(row, 'X')) > 0)
                return new int[] { index, column };
            index++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        String newline = System.lineSeparator();
        for (char[] row : map)
            string.append(row).append(newline);
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

```
11111
1 X 1
1 1 1
1   1
111 1

[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static char[][] readMaze(Path file) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(file).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
}
```

will read your maze without needing any header. Just store the maze itself.

Your problem arises from reading the line separators. These are present, as not consumed by `readLine` calls

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be in the logic related to reading the file and storing it in the map.

You can simply read the text file and store all the lines.

Then, total row = number of lines

And total column = size of first line

In this way, you won't have to open the file multiple times.

About reading each line to store in the char array =>

As your input contains spaces and newlines, it would be better to use `reader.readline()` instead of `reader.read()`.

Read more about read() and readLine() from below:

[BufferedReader read() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190995/bufferedreader-read-not-working)

[BufferedReader will not read final line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446847/bufferedreader-will-not-read-final-line-of-input)

However, you can also use simpler logic like below sample code to read the file and store it:

```
private static char[][] getMapFromFile() throws IOException {

    List < String > allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
    int totalRows = allLines.size();
    int totalColumns = allLines.get(0).length();

    char[][] map = new char[totalRows][totalColumns];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        String currentLine = allLines.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++) {
            map[i][j] = currentLine.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the double for-loop to a single one `int row = 0; for (String line : allLines) map[row++] = line.toCharArray();`